# Call event onchange, onclick

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have two element `<input>` and `<a>` below:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" class="inputUpload" id="fileUpload" onchange="changeAvatar()" onclick="selectFile()" />

<a onclick="selectImage()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="pull-right">Select image</a>
```

How to call event `onchange` and `onclick` from function:

```
function selectImage(){ };
```

Comment: Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try that if You used jQuery:

`function selectImage() {
   $("#fileUpload").trigger("tap");
}`

or

`function selectImage() {
   $("#fileUpload").trigger("click");
}`

Comment: Thanks @migacz1125!